# node.js can not connect to redis using docker-compose?

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, docker-compose

- I am deploying a nodejs app using docker-compose. But for some reason app container can not connect to redis container eventhough I did using depends_on, and on conatainer app, i still can ping redis docker. Yet the pm2 logs still show that it can not connect.
- And then when i detached the connect redis code and run it alone, it still run ok. I think maybe its conflict with other modules so i posted my package.json list.

my app code:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
const subscriber = redis.createClient();

var sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: 'abc',
    store: new redisStore({ host: "redis-docker" ,url: "redis-docker", port: 
     "6379", client: client }),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { maxAge: 604800000 }
});
```

docker-compose file:

```
docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'
services:
  redis-docker:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis
    networks:
      - abc
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    hostname: redis-docker
    # command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]

  app:
    container_name: app
    image: app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "4004:4004"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    env_file:
      - .env
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - redis-docker
    # command: ["npm", "start"]
    networks:
      - abc
    links:
      - redis-docker

volumes:
  redis-data:
networks:
  abc:
```

this is all the modules i have used:

```
node
{
  "name": "webphone-ui",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo 'OK'"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "abortcontroller-polyfill": "^1.1.8",
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "connect-multiparty": "^2.1.0",
    "connect-redis": "^3.3.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "cron": "^1.6.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.5.7",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-ip": "^1.0.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.10.0",
    "form-data": "^2.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.0",
    "mime": "^1.6.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.4.1",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-audio-player": "^0.6.4",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^4.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-multilingual": "^1.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "3.0.5",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.3",
    "redis": "^2.8.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "rotating-file-stream": "^1.3.4",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "sweetalert": "^2.0.8",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.0",
    "winston": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Please help me, if anyone pass this problem before. I searched and try a lot of way but no hope.
Thanks.

Comment: you have already define a network between them, I suggest to remove the `links` from `compose`

Comment: i did try with and without links, its still come to the same error.
Thanks.

Comment: yes that will not fix the problem , I just wanted to make you aware the when using networks then there is no need to use links :)

Comment: yes, thank you. I understand that.

Comment: What's the actual error you get?  It seems a little odd to have the host name twice, and the `url:` you specify isn't URL syntax.  `port:` almost might need to be a number and not a string (and you can likely omit it for the default Redis port).

Answer (score -1):

**Update:**

Before the further investigation, It seems connection string is not valid.

```
var client = redis.createClient(6379,"redis-docker"); 
    app.use(session({
      secret: 'ThisIsHowYouUseRedisSessionStorage',
      name: '_redisPractice',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      cookie: { secure: false }, // Note that the cookie-parser module is no longer needed
      store: new redisStore({ host: 'redis-docker', port: 6379, client: redisClient, ttl: 86400 }),
    }));
```

[managing-node-js-express-sessions-with-redis](https://medium.com/mtholla/managing-node-js-express-sessions-with-redis-94cd099d6f2f)

Next step, There are other approaches, One approach that you can try and will definitely work follow these steps.

- create network `docker network create abc`
- then inspect `docker inspect network abc`
- get the ip from config

Here is config in network inspect

```
 "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": {},
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.26.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.26.0.1"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Update your nodejs script

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(6379,"172.26.0.1");
client.on('error', function(err){
  console.log('Something went wrong ', err)
});
client.set('my test key', 'my test value', redis.print);
client.get('my test key', function(error, result) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('GET result ->', result)
})
```

You compose do not need linking.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  redis-docker:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis
    networks:
      - abc
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    hostname: redis-docker
    # command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]

  app:
    container_name: app
    image: app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "4004:4004"
    env_file:
      - .env
    build: .
    command: tail -f /dev/null # or your command
    networks:
      - abc
volumes:
  redis-data:
networks:
  abc:
    driver: bridge
```

[image]

Docker network

[image]

Comment: This IP address will change the next time you restart containers.  Hard-coding it in the application is definitely wrong.  Looking it up at all is almost never necessary.

Comment: It is Network IP, and I think it will not change @DavidMaze? until network it destroyed?

Comment: you can look into this https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#default-networks

Comment: The network IP persist, the issue was in the connection string, but this the one way to investigate the issue, as I mentioned at very start of answer !

Comment: The network IP won't change unless the network is destroyed and recreated (which `docker-compose down` does).  The container IP won't change unless the container is destroyed and recreated (which `docker-compose up` could do on some routine changes).  Routine things like rebooting the system or porting the setup to a different host will throw this all out of whack.

Comment: `docker-compose` down nothing to do with network nor with `system reboot` @DavidMaze pls verify it on your local system, will only remove when you run `docker network rm `. So the IP persist on `docker-compose down` or also persist on system reboot or shut down. pls, try it :) also here network is created separately